# Interpreting ARIMA prediction results

Tags: time-series, forecasting, predictive-models, arima

I have used an ARIMA(1,1,0) model on a stationary time series.
The time series shows amount of fires (number between 0 and 12) per day over a few years in regions of Moscow.
Both fitted and predicted values from ARIMA, however, lie between -4 and +4.

[image: Green is fitted values, grey is observed values]

Predicted values also coverage to zero almost instantly.
[image: Red is fitted, grey is observed, dashed red is predicted, blue indicates end of training set and start of control set]
I only need to predict for a week ahead. The model predicts negative amounts of fires.

[image: Red is fitted, grey is observed, dashed red is predicted, blue indicates end of training set and start of control set]

How do I interpret the results of ARIMA prediction? If these are not absolute values, how do I transition to absolute values?

You can view the IPython notebook with more details here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/592ug74i4h1i7tb/ARIMA%2B2005-2008-eng%20%281%29.html?dl=0

The `results.fit().summary()` output is as follows:

```
                             ARIMA Model Results                              
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                  D.САО   No. Observations:                 1247
Model:                 ARIMA(1, 1, 0)   Log Likelihood               -2759.563
Method:                       css-mle   S.D. of innovations              2.212
Date:                Thu, 04 Aug 2016   AIC                           5525.126
Time:                        10:01:24   BIC                           5540.512
Sample:                    01-02-2005   HQIC                          5530.911
                         - 06-01-2008                                         
===============================================================================
                  coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const           0.0040      0.041      0.096      0.923      -0.077       0.085
ar.L1.D.САО    -0.5114      0.024    -21.020      0.000      -0.559      -0.464
                                    Roots                                    
=============================================================================
                 Real           Imaginary           Modulus         Frequency
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
AR.1           -1.9554           +0.0000j            1.9554            0.5000
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: *I have used an ARIMA(1,1,0) model on a stationary time series.* There already is a discrepancy. ARIMA(p,1,q) is for nonstationary, unit-root models. Also, it is really strange that the fitted values are considerably below the actual values; you should investigate that. Could you post your model estimation output? By the way, there are versions of ARIMA model for integer-values time series. You should be able to look them up online (I have never used them, so I cannot recommend a refence.)

Comment: @RichardHardy I will include the model estimation output into the question

Comment: @RichardHardy removing the differencing order parameter produces the following results: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0l94vdn6x5kndnq/arima100.png?dl=0

Comment: It will take a while for me to get back to you, sorry. A quick note: the intercept seems too low, so you get underfit and underprediction. Why is that happening?..

Comment: @RichardHardy I have no idea

Comment: Hi: If you're dealing with counts, it's best not to use a regular ARIMA model. I think someone has done some work on  forecasting counts and there's even a text on it but I can't remember the name of it. All my books are in storage at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

No expert but is it because you are modelling on differenced data? make sure you are modelling on data that has not been differenced or I think you will essentially difference it twice using d=1.